# javascript text to speech api implementation in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, text-to-speech

when i use this code in an .html file, it works perfectly:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery plugin for Text to Speech - demo</title>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="speakGenerator.js"></script>
<script src="speakClient.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">    
<button id="button" onclick="speak('I know I know I know')">Talk</button>
<div id="audio"></div>   
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But when i try to implement it in asp.net like below: it doesnt work, no voice is heard although the page at the click of the button sends a request to the localhost: but no voice is heard.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div id="container">    
<button id="button" onclick="speak('Hello world')">Talk</button>
<div id="audio"></div>

</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Check your includes...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just forgot to include your external js files...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="speakGenerator.js"></script>
<script src="speakClient.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="container">    
<button id="button" onclick="speak('Hello world');return false;">Talk</button>
<div id="audio"></div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @user3079575 Can you add links or update your question with source for `speakgenerator.js` and `speakclient.js` please? I just noticed that the scripts are inside a `asp:Content` control. If you view source on the page can you see the `script` references?

Comment: i removed the scripts from the content tag and put them in the head tag in the master page, still nothing changed

Comment: I just noticed that you say "the click of the button sends a request to the localhost"  - so clicking the button is causing an ASP.NET postback? Check code again and try returning false from the `OnClick` on your button.